# Grub not installing properly with two separate discs

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub2

I'm trying to set up a dual boot Windows 7/ Ubuntu 11.10. I have 3 drives:

Linux - sda1
Swap  - sda5

Windows - sdb1

Media - sdc1

I installed Windows first so that it didn't muck up my GRUB loader. While installing GRUB, it was supposed to install to the master boot record on sda. However, after completing the installation, my computer only ever boots directly into Linux. I tried issuing a `grub-install` and even `update-grub` but grub simply never appears. Is there something special I need to do to make the grub installer aware that there is an OS on a separate disc? I've honestly never had this issue before but I think I've ever only dual booted on the same disc.

Comment: Normally Ubuntu sets up Grub to work automatically in a situation like this, but it sometimes messes up. Please post the content of `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

So what do you get on the boot menu? GNU/Linux only? How are you configuring it? If this is some automated installer, I guess there's an issue with the installer.

You can always configure `GRUB` manually, adding the entry for Windows -- it should be a matter of grabbing [one of the dual-boot configs out there](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_Dual_Boot#Dual_Booting_from_Multiple_Hard_Drives) and changing what needs to be changed. In this example, it's already written for two different disks, although it's for arch and Windows (but you just need to add the Windows entry, anyway). I believe Ubuntu now uses `GRUB 2`, so [another example, from the Gentoo Wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Grub2#Microsoft_Windows_Entry) is in place to show how it can be done.